# Position of « nouveau »

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

In my oxford-hachette dictionary they have an example sentence of « porter un regard nouveau sur quelque chose » which translates to "take a fresh look at something". I wanted to ask why is nouveau placed behind the noun here instead of in front like I was always taught?

Comment: The meaning is essentially identical between *un regard nouveau* and *un nouveau regard*.

Comment: to insist on "nouveau"
nouveau regard = another look
regarde nouveau = fresh look